# Primary ideals as functions vanishing to a certain degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be the field of complex numbers. Let $I$ be a primary ideal in $k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$, let $\operatorname{rad}(I)=P$, and let $X$ be the algebraic variety corresponding to $P$.

I am trying to find in the literature a definite statement giving a description of $I$ in terms of vanishing along $X$ to a certain degree. For completeness I state a question below, but the description doesn't have to be exactly like in that question, but it should be in "the same spirit" (however, I don't know any counterexamples to the description in the question, so please let me know if that description is to naive).

$\newcommand{\D}[3]{\frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial{#3}^{#1}}}$
A ``vector field'' means a vector field  whose components are defined by polynomial functions. Given a vector field $v$ and a function $f$  let $\D{n}{f}{v}$ be the partial derivative of $f$ in the direction of $v$. taken $n$ times.

*Question*: Is it true that there exist vector fields 
\begin{align*}
v_{1,1}, &\ldots, v_{1,k_1}\\
v_{2,1}, &\ldots, v_{2,k_2}\\
&\ldots \\
v_{g,1},&\ldots, v_{g,k_g}
\end{align*}
defined on a Zariski dense subset $U$ of $X$ such that

1. for any $j=1,\ldots,g$ and $u\in U$  we have that the span of $v_{j+1,1}(u),\ldots v_{j+1,k_{j+1}}(u)$ is contained in the span of $v_{j,1}(u),\ldots, v_{j,k_j}(u)$
2. We have that $f\in k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ is an element of $I$ if and only if for all $u\in U$ we have $f(u)=0$, and furthermore for all $i$ and all $j$ we have $\D{i}{f}{v_{i,j}}(u)=0$.

In some standard textbooks the existence of this sort of description is ``suggested between the lines'', but I haven't been able to find a definite statement.